# how to train spacy model which treats & and 'and' similar for accurate prediction

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

i've trained a spacy NER model which has text mapped to Company entity during training as -

```
John & Doe & One pvt ltd -> Company
```

Now in some cases I find, if giving sentence as below during prediction is being categorized as Others-

```
John and Doe and One pvt ltd -> Other
```

What should be done to overcome this problem where we have cases of "& == and" and "v == vs == versus" etc cases to be understood by the model has same meaning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these kinds of cases you want to add lexeme norms or token norms.

```py
# lexeme norm
nlp.vocab["and"].norm_ = "&"
# token norm
doc[1].norm_ = "&"
```

The statistical models all use `token.norm` instead of `token.orth` as a feature by default. You can set `token.norm_` for an individual token in a doc (sometimes you might want normalizations that depend on the context), or set `nlp.vocab["word"].norm_` as the default for any token that doesn't have an individual `token.norm` set.

If you add lexeme norms to the vocab and save the model with `nlp.to_disk`, the lexeme norms are included in the saved model.